# Change the width of a frame according to the width of the other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `div#in` and I want the width of my iFrame to fill the rest of the `div#di` space if the width of the `div#in` changes
Friends, how can I do this?

```css
#di{
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#in{
  display: block;
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 56px;
  width: 50px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div id="di">
        <div id="in">test by change witdh</div>
        <iframe src="https://www.bing.com"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add `width: 100%;` css style to your iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
#myIFrame {
  position: relative;   
  width: 100%;
}
```

Where **#myIFrame** is an id that i gave to your frame.